# Raid Scaling using MDADM

Tags: raid

I have 3 equally-sized hard drives. I would like to use `mdadm` to do software RAID scaling on these. Is this possible in Ubuntu 12.04? Is there another tool I should use?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely it is, and `mdadm` is indeed the tool with which you would want to do this.

When you boot up your live USB or CD to install Ubuntu, create the logical RAID devices via CLI prior to beginning then installation. Here is a link that nicely lays out how to use `mdadm` to set up your software RAID devices:

[RAID setup - Linux Raid Wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup)

After setting up your RAID devices, start up the Ubuntu installer, select "Something Else" when you get to the disk/storage part, then assign filesystems to your RAID devices.

Note 1: You can optionally set up [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) on top of your RAID devices created through mdadm and build your filesystems that way prior to launching the Ubuntu installer.

Note 2: Take care to exclude your Live USB device from any RAID or LVM configuration you perform.

EDIT: It is not necessary to use a Live USB/CD if you are creating a RAID device to mount somewhere and use as a NFS server or something to that effect.